# How to Posting Code Blocks on a WordPress Site?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm looking for a plugin or something to post lines of code like in the image below, i want to edit my post page from the admin panel if it's possible.
any ideas?!

[image: example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the plugin `SyntaxHighlighter Evolved`

[Link to plugin site here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/)

If you just wrap you code in bracket tags like this:

```
[php]
<?php
  $currCat = get_category(get_query_var('cat'));
  $cat_name = $currCat->name;
  $cat_id   = get_cat_ID( $cat_name );
?>
[/php]
```

It will automatically create code highlighted when you publish your post, like this: https://techtuts.co/wordpress-how-to-do-pagination-on-category-page/

Answer (score 0):

Using [Crayon Syntax Highlighter](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/crayon-syntax-highlighter/), it will auto format the  tag as a code block.